# Retention Time of Isotopologues

Tags: analytical-chemistry, gas-phase-chemistry, isotopologues

In several sources I have read that heavier isotopologues eluate earlier than lighter ones.
As explanation vapor isotope effects are given.
But this is something I do not understand. I tought in a GC column substances are separated by their different vapor pressures and the longer a substance stays in the gas phase the earlier it eluates. Heavy isotopologues have have a smaller vapour pressure and should therefore eluate later.
What I am missing?

Comment: You may miss the shift of the distribution constant between phases.

Comment: Could you please explain this a little bit more.

Comment: Imagine there is a polar and nonpolar compound with the same saturated vapour pressure, having nonpolar SF. Which would have the longer elution time ? Now generalize for compounds with different distribution constant between MF/SF, or the equivalent Henry constant.

Comment: Isn't the boiling point what matters.

Comment: Think longer.... Imagine you have initially 2 containers with the same initial analyte vapour pressure. Then you insert there the SF. Both analytes have different KD. Will they have the same final vapour pressure ?

Comment: Sorry what does KD mean?

Comment: $K_\mathrm{D}=\frac {c_\mathrm{SF}}{c_\mathrm{MF}}$ means distribution constant.